# Пользовательское текстовое поле

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в c# winforms vs2010 реализовать следующий элемент формы (текстовое поле с вводом текста только во вторую строку):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а обязателно win forms

Comment: А не хотите для этого использовать WPF? Если уже много написано, то вы можете этот элемент управления написать на WPF и внедрить его на Windows Forms. Просто, по честному: это будет очень муторно. Вам придётся тогда пойти таким неизящным путём: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903348/1548895

Comment: Поместите на `Panel` сверху `Label`, снизу `TextBox`. У текстбокса отключите рамку, у панели, наоборот, включите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А не хотите для этого использовать WPF? Если уже много написано, то вы можете этот элемент управления написать на WPF и внедрить его на Windows Forms. Просто, по честному: это будет очень муторно.

Если вы всё-таки решились остановить свой выбор на Windows Forms, то вам придётся тогда пойти подобным неизящным путём: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903348/1548895

То есть

- Удалить границу у текстового поля (оно будет только для ввода текста, к примеру, для значения `2,7102`),
- Создать панель `Panel` с границей (поставить можно в системный цвет), будто это "большое" текстовое поле с надписью, поместить туда `Label` (с текстом `Асфальтобетонные покрытия`) и вышеназванный `TextBox` без границы.
- По-хорошему также надо реализовать события получения и потери фокуса, которое будет, как минимум менять границу.

Чтобы этого не делать кучу раз, поместите эти элементы управления в `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант

1. Создаете UserControl у него делаете границу.
2. В контроле формируете ваш дизайн контрола из разных элементов.

И получится что такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот тут можно скачать пример [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://yadi.sk/d/XpI9ULEs3YFjeJ)

Текст для Текстбокса задается через 
свойство Content  а заголовок через свойство Title

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста пример подобного элемента в wpf winforms (например, http://www.vo-da.ru/tool/wastewater)?

Comment: нет таких все самому делать нада